# How to get javascript variable with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

When I check request data in Postman it returns HTML file and contains JavaScript value.

```
<html>
  <body>
     HTML VALUES...
  </body>
  <script>
    var _ITEMID = '29041549';
    var ITEM_VID = '612c86e6c6f7840001d0c821';
    var _SOLDOUT = '1' == 0;
    var _DISCOUNTPRICE = '110.00';
    var _SIZE = 'S,M,L,XL';
    var _ITEMTYPE = '0';
    var _COLORPICS = '';
  </script>
  <script>another script value</script>
  <script>another script value</script>
  <script>another script value</script>
  <script>another script value</script>
</html>
```

I use `got` package to request data.
And I want to get script's value, but when I tried this code, it returns undefined.

I already checked this article and modify this codes but it seems it doesn't fit my case.

```
const got = require('got');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const data = await got(`https://www.vvic.com/item/${itemDetailURL}.html`);
// console.log(data);
const $ = cheerio.load(data);
const calData = $('script').get()[0];
console.log(calData);  // Returns undefined
```

[console.log($('script'));]

```
LoadedCheerio {
  length: 0,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      type: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array]
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *1]
  },
  prevObject: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      type: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array]
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *1]
  }
}
```

[console.log($('script').get());]

```
[] // Returns empty array
```

Comment: What does it render when you uncomment `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: I think `console.log($(window))` will give you more insights.

Comment: What does `console.log($('script'));` return? Also what does `console.log($('script').get());` return?

Comment: @DhruvShah When I console.log it, it has entire HTML file

Comment: @Molda I edited my question that console.log each $('script') and $('script').get()

Comment: I just noticed that your script tags are outside the body element. Try to move them inside.